# In SHM why do we use $\omega^2$?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

My question is why do we use $\omega^2$? in the equation $A=-\omega^2x$.

Why we just don't call it $A=-k/m×x$

I want to know the actual reason behind this.

Comment: Would you rather write various functions of $\omega t$ or $\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t$ when discussing such oscillations?

Comment: Okay that means its only for to make the equation look neat and clean. Is that the point?

Comment: Also, not everything that oscillates is a mass at the end of a spring.

Comment: For instance, a pendulum under the small-angle approximation has $\omega^2=g/l$, where $l$ is the length of the pendulum. Etc.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of this thing

Comment: I guess it's just sort of standard substitution probably done to kick square root function while using integration if at some point required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author used hindsight: after playing around with the equations he/she found out that $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$ is a nice parameter and instead of first deriving the solution and then define $\omega$ the author is making the derivation nicer by defining it now.

By defining $\omega$ the solution looks like
$$x(t)=A_1\cos(\omega t)+A_2\sin(\omega t)$$

Comment: Okay so in your perspective after carrying out the experiment practically he/she came to a conclusion that we should use omega² instead of just using omega. Is that something are you trying to say? So then what absurd thing would happen if we will use only omega not omega²?

Comment: @TejasDahake Not experiment but derivation. But yes that's what I'm trying to say. You could have defined $\omega=k/m$ as well. It is just a definition. But that would make the final result less nice. Generally you can define whatever you want but it only makes sense to define things when it makes your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for your help! People just tell while deriving that it's just we have to square it because to keep that k/m positive but it doesn't makes sense to me, since the spring constant and mass are always positive so the whole fraction that is k/m itself becomes a positive quantity. so that's why I was confused, thanks again.

Comment: And I got to know that lets take a general equation for displacement in SHM that is x=Asin(ωt+Φ) here its omega because A=-ω²x has ω², hence general equation for displacement can be written as x=Asin(√k/√m ×t +Φ) otherwise if was just A=-ωx then it will sound as x=Asin( √ω×t+Φ) or x=Asin(√√k/√√m ×t +Φ) which looks very bad while solving. That's the point I understood.

Comment: You got it my man.

Answer (score 3):

For one dimensional motion one way of defining simple harmonic motion is to say that
(a) the acceleration, $\vec a = a \,\hat x$, is proportional to the displacement, $\vec x = x \, \hat x$, from a fixed point and
(b) the acceleration is always directed towards the fixed point.

From condition (a) one can write $\vec a \propto \vec x \Rightarrow a\,\hat x \propto x\,\hat x \Rightarrow a\propto x$ where $a$ and $x$ are components and
from condition (b) one can write $a = -\omega^2 x$ knowing that $\omega^2$ is always going to be a **positive** number.

So if the component of the displacement is positive then the component of the acceleration is negative, ie the direction of the acceleration is towards the origin and if the component of the displacement is negative then the component of the acceleration is positive, ie the direction of the acceleration is towards the origin.

There are also useful linear relationships between $\omega$ and the frequency of the motion, $f$, and the period of the motion, $T$, viz $\omega = 2 \pi f$ and $\omega = 2\pi/T$

Comment: but if we can see that omega is k/m, l/g etc. So we can clearly say that the spring constant, mass, length, magnitude of accn due to gravity etc. are always positive. So then why we focus on positive and negative if these quantities are always positive and hence there ratio will also going to be positive?

Comment: In the general equation for shm you could introduce a constant, say $p$ and state that it is positive, but having the constant as a squared quantity will always ensure that the constant is positive.